# combobox with big store. how to set value

Tags: extjs

I have a combobox, which has these properties:

```
displayField:'name',
valueField:'id'
```

Its store may contain thousands or millions of rows. When a user pushes one button, the server returns the json for the form which looks like this:

```
{"field_one":"abrakadabra","combobox_with_large_store":"123"}
```

Here `123` is an `id` of a particular row. I then need to show a "user-friendly" value (displayField), but to do this I should first load this value to the store. But I'm not sure, what it the best way to do this - should I track `change` event or something else. The problem with `change` event is that a user may print some values in the combo to query its store and among those values may be numeric ones (so it is impossible to differentiate between numeric id which is a true value and some numeric values printed by the user). So, what I need is an advise on how to set and load value of the combobox with large store (having in mind that the user may query this store with numeric values).

Comment: Can we see how does your model and store look?

Comment: At this moment I have a trivial case. A form, two fields (one of them is a combobox with "large" store) and a button. A user pushes the button, the server returns json. On a client I do form.setValues(json). As a result first field is set, the second (combo) is not because it is not loaded. So, what I want to know - is what is the best strategy to load the store. On `change` event or not? What I do not like about change event is a possibility of vicious circle: try to set value first (change by form.setValues) -> store is empty, then load -> change value again.

Comment: So, imagine we are at the moment when the server return json with an id of a row, that should be loaded to the store. What should we do next - what events to listen to, when to load, when to do final setting?

Comment: If the store was relatively small, I would have `autoLoad: true`. Here I have `autoLoad:false`. So, how should I deal with all that in terms of events and methods?

Comment: I don't suppose you intend to display thousands of options in your select options? Can you please elaborate the requirement as such?

Comment: You are right. I do not intend to do such a thing. What I want is to load the store (actually one row corresponding to id returned by the server) and to set the combobox value. The question is what event to listen to?

Comment: "The requirement as such" is to set combobox value. The problem is combobox store is to large to autoLoad it.

Comment: I am facing the same challenge. This should be quite usual scenario in any application. @Jacobian, Did you find any solution for this ?